# Read multiple files (wavread)

Tags: matlab

I want to read several files from certain directory. Here is my script:

```
prefix = '\wav\';
wav_arr = ['1.wav'; '2.wav'; '3.wav'];
wav_arr = cellstr(wav_arr);

len = length(wav_arr);
sig = [];
fs = [];
for i = 1:len
    path = strcat(pwd, prefix, wav_arr(i));
    [s, curr_fs] = audioread(path);
    sig = [sig s];
    fs = [fs curr_fs];
end
```

But I receive the error:

```
Error using which
Argument must contain a string.

Error in audiovideo.internal.absolutePathForReading (line 7)
whichFileName = which(filename);

Error in audioread (line 74)
filename = audiovideo.internal.absolutePathForReading(...

Error in main_experiment (line 14)
    [s, curr_fs] = audioread(path);
```

The problem is that `path` is the `1x1 cell`, it's not a `string`. And executing `cellstr()` for `path` does not work.

Comment: path is a matlab function avoid to use this name as a variable !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for i = 1:len
    path = strcat(pwd, prefix, wav_arr(i));
    [s, curr_fs] = audioread(path);
    sig = [sig s];
    fs = [fs curr_fs];
end
```

become

```
for i = 1:len
    path = strcat(pwd, prefix, wav_arr{i});
    [s, curr_fs] = audioread(path);
    sig = [sig s];
    fs = [fs curr_fs];
end
```

That's all, read the doc about the cells in matlab to understand the difference between cell(1) and cell{1}

Comment: instead of `strcat(pwd, prefix, wav_arr{i});` I will suggest to use `fullfile(pwd, prefix, wav_arr{i});` instead. The intent is much clearer IMHO. Further, it allows to use `prefix = 'wav'` and not worry about having the correct slashes. Also rename `path` to `filename` as you yourself suggested :)